# Cannot get value of checkbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I spent the day on this issue that you will probably find very basic... I've read a lot of things on the web but could not get my stuff to work .

I have a simple 2 radio fields in a form and I would like to retrieve the value of the checked radio button. Here is my form  :

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="radio radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" id="id1" data-toggle="radio" name="deliveryMethod" value="courrier" checked="">
              <label for="id1">Courrier</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" id="id2" data-toggle="radio" name="deliveryMethod" value="local">
              <label for="id2">Local</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

My js is :

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
            console.log(this.value)
});
```

I cannot get the right value. I get the opposite value (local when Courrier is selected, and vice versa). I also get both values when I click the labels...

I'm really lost.

Thanks ahead for your help.

Comment: You code should work, make sure you have included the jquery correct

Comment: Post a working code snippet demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have code modifying your functionality further down in your JS? (Duplication possibly?) I created a JSFiddle and it worked correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/4gZAT/1580/

Answer (score 1):

I just pasted your code into a jsfiddle and it works correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/c42vd3m9/1/

My only thought is that it's possible that you incorrectly copied

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
        console.log(this.value)
});
```

into your document.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, it is working just fine.

Here is a fully working example you should try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>RadioButton Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="radio radio-inline">
               <input type="radio" id="id1" data-toggle="radio" name="deliveryMethod" value="courrier" checked="">
               <label for="id1">Courrier</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio radio-inline">
               <input type="radio" id="id2" data-toggle="radio" name="deliveryMethod" value="local">
               <label for="id2">Local</label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
                 console.log(this.value)
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**EXTRA**

If you want to GET the first value (when the page is rendered first time) then you should try using some jQuery function, like "on ready" or "on load".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Perform something here...

});


//or

$(document).load(function(){
   // Perform something here...
});
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. The problem must be different. I'll continue to investigate.

Comment: But did it work? Have you tried running exactly the code I gave you? Keep updating it so we can solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

yes your code is working.. i also tried with your code.

try this https://jsfiddle.net/eaje2ywt/4/

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to w3schools, this is normal behaviour
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The onchange event occurs when the value of an
>   element has been changed. For radiobuttons and checkboxes, the
>   onchange event occurs when the checked state has been changed.
>
> **Tip:** This event is similar to the *oninput* event. The difference is that the
>   oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an element has
>   changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses focus, after the
>   content has been changed. The other difference is that the onchange
>   event also works on  elements.

Therefore, whenever you deselect the radio-button (by selecting the other one), you get its value. So you can use either oninput or onchange, depending on what point you want the action to occur.